# Why is my Runge-Kutta Python script defining elements of an array in this abnormal way?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, runge-kutta

I am a newcomer to Python, my knowledge of the programming language is still in its infancy, so I copied the Runge-Kutta Python script shown [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Runge-Kutta_method#Python) and modified it for my purposes. Here is my current script:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
a=0
b=np.pi
g=9.8
l=1
N=1000

def RK4(f):
    return lambda t, y, dt: (
            lambda dy1: (
            lambda dy2: (
            lambda dy3: (
            lambda dy4: (dy1 + 2*dy2 + 2*dy3 + dy4)/6
            )( dt * f( t + dt  , y + dy3   ) )
        )( dt * f( t + dt/2, y + dy2/2 ) )
        )( dt * f( t + dt/2, y + dy1/2 ) )
        )( dt * f( t       , y         ) )

from math import sqrt
dy = RK4(lambda t, y: -y)

t, y, dt = 0., 1., np.divide((b-a),float(N))
i=0
T=np.zeros((N+1,1))
DY=T
Y=T
while t < (b-dt):
    T[i]=t
    DY[i]=dy(t,y,dt)
    t, y = t + dt, y + dy( t, y, dt )
    Y[i]=y
    i=i+1

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(T,Y)
plt.show()
```

You can ignore the g and l variables in the first few lines, I was going to solve the problem of the simple pendulum, but then I remembered this is a first order ODE solver, so now my ODE is `dy/dx=-y`. I have been running this in IPython. I was expecting `T` to be an array, basically the equivalent to `linspace(0,pi,N+1)` in MATLAB. So T is to be a set of N+1 evenly-spaced values between (and including) 0 and pi, but instead this is a sample of its contents (which came as an output from running `T`):

```
In [101]: T
Out[101]:
array([[ 0.99686334],
       [ 0.99373651],
       [ 0.9906195 ],
       ...,
       [ 0.04334989],
       [ 0.04321392],
       [ 0.        ]])
```

(including the Input and Output lines to give some context as to what I am referring to here, in case it is unclear). Oh and by-the-way, if you're wondering why I didn't use `T=np.linspace(a,b,num=N+1)` instead of defining it in this loop well it is because this gives similarly unusual T arrays.

Comment: I can only wonder about the nested lambdas: that feels more lisp than anything Python. Other weirdness would include `np.divide((b-a),float(N))` instead of `(b-a)/N` (with the proper future import as necessary).

Comment: I used that `np.divide` because of my belief (that seems unjustified now as I just tried running (b-a)/N and it ran without hitch) that (b-a)/N would return the nearest integer only and not a decimal. Making the substitution you suggested, failed to make any difference, though.

Comment: Anyone care to tell me why this question of mine is being downvoted? Like I acknowledge the cause was, as LutzL said, how I defined DY and Y, and while that makes me feel a little silly, I'm learning which I thought was the purpose of this website, to help those struggling learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
DY=T
Y=T
```

you are only copying the references, they all point to the same array object. Essentially, the contents of all will be `Y` as it is the last assigned.

Use `T.copy()` to get a separate array object.